# How to use external js File function in angular web application

Tags: angular, external-js

I just want to use a external js file to build an animation in my angular web application.

Online at W3C site I have found this:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_image_compare

I just want to use this js file in my angular application, but it was not working.

```
 $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: false,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplayTimeout: 3000,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  dots: false,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 3
    },
    1000: {
      items: 5
    }
  }
})
```

in external js file there is this function, How can I use this fucntion in my angular web application.

Can somebody give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The right way is to do that is to convert the code into Typescript.
You should go step by step implementing Angular logic.

You could implement a directive and call it wherever you need it.
https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Comment: But I don't want to change any code in external js file.